# jqPlot - Insert Date (yyyy-mm-dd) to (dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: javascript, date, format, jqplot

The input in the example (jqPlot) code is yyyy-mm-dd.

```
var line1=[['2008-08-12',4], ['2008-08-13',6.5], ['2008-08-14',5.7], ['2008-08-15',9], ['2008-08-16',8.2], ['2008-08-17',7.2], ['2008-08-18',3.2]];
```

But we work here with the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm.
Should i better transform the input to yyyy/mm/dd or is it easy to change?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: if that's the date format jqplot is expecting, then don't mess with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input date formatted like :

```
var line2=[['30/09/2008 4:00PM',4],['30/10/2008 4:00PM',6.5], ['30/11/2008 4:00PM',5.7], ['30/12/2008 4:00PM',9], ['30/01/2009 4:00PM',8.2]];
```

are understandable by jqplot. You can therefore use `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` format.

See working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/WSdU4/) where I add a new variable : `var line2` to display date in dd/mm/yyyy format.

Note that you can specify date ticks rendering using

```
axes:{xaxis:{
  renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
  tickOptions: {
    formatString: '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'
  },
}},
```

See more about `DateAxisRenderer` in jqPlot documentation [here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js.html).